# email and landing Pages AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am very new to using AMPScript both for Landing Pages as well as on emails. Hoping the SFMC Demi Gods can provide me with example for the following functions:

1. **pre-populate** a Landing Page with Data Extension values already gathered and update them as needed by completing the form.
2. make fields required e.g. first name and email address - while using Landing Pages Smart Capture and NOT Cloud Pages.
3. Perform a lookup on a table - (ET – SFMC) does not support lookup fields with the Smart Capture.
4. Display personalization using Data Extensions on a smart capture or a HTML paste field such as email address, and prior purchase.
5. Display a different thank you/final page based on Gender on a Smart Capture Landing Page, if that is possible.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  You're unlikely to get many answers without some details about what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you provided in your question and what I understood you are asking, see below answers. If you can provide more details on your question, I may be able to provide better solutions.

1. Use the `Lookup()` function to gather these as variables and display
   the variables.  E.g. `SET @YourVariable =
   (Lookup(yourDE,"FieldtoLookup","SubscriberKey",SubscriberKeyValue)` and
   in the HTML, use `%%=v(@YourVariable)=%%` to display it.
2. Use `required="required"` or add in some JavaScript validation script
   into the HTML.
3. AMPScript is a server-side language, it cannot be used to look up
   info that is in the HTML (e.g. a table). To pull values from tables, try JavaScript or jQuery for this.
4. You can use `AttributeValue()` if coming from `MicrositeURL()` or you
   can do a variable with a lookup, like explained in #1. You would
   need to pass a parameter in the link, something like
   `?Email=Sampleemail` to use this.
5. You would need to change the POST location or otherwise edit the
   processing page to use AMPScript to pull gender (e.g.
   `RequestParameter()`) and use `IF ELSE` statement to define
   content/styling.

Reference:

[**MicrositeURL() & RequestParameter()**](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/)

[**AttributeValue() & v()**](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/)

[**Lookup()**](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/)